# How do I change the theme of only one page in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I have an general education landing page in Wordpress, thats needs a new theme. I want to just change that ONE page but not impact any other page. I have a business premium account with Wordpress. Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the theme just in one page. To customize that page you would need to create a custom template by creating a template or a file on your server to only affect that page.

Something like:
 [Page templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)

Or:

`page-87.php` 87 being the page ID

`front-page.php`If the page you want to costumize is the front page

`page-landing.php`If the name of the page is "landing

This might help: [WpBeginner](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/)